# Detect existence of next handler in Angular JavaScript promise chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-http-interceptors

Given the following two `$resource` examples:

```
var exampleOne = $resource('/path').save(objectOne);
exampleOne.$promise.then(function (success) {}, function (error) {});

var exampleTwo = $resource('/path').save(objectTwo);
exampleTwo.$promise.then(function (success) {});
```

[NOTE: Example two contains no error handler]

And an interceptor that sits below all `$http` requests:

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q) {
   function error(response) {
       if (response.status === 400) {
           return $q.reject(response);
       }
       else {
           $location.path('/error/page');
       }
       return $q.reject(response);
   }

   return {
       'responseError': error
   };
}

$httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
```

How can I make the interceptor not reject when the example resources `$promise.then()` contain no error callback? If the call back exists as in `exampleOne` then I wish to reject, but if not as in `exampleTwo` then I wish to redirect to the error page thus changing the conditional to something like:

```
if (response.status === 400 && $q.unresolvedPromises.doIndeedExist()) { ...
```

Why? Because only some situations in my project call for handling a `400` in a user friendly way, thus I'd like to eliminate many duplicate error callbacks or having to place a list of uncommon situations in the interceptor. I'd like the interceptor to be able to decide based on the presence of another handler in the promise chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simply put it is impossible**, you can't detect if someone will attach a handler in some point in the future just like you can't tell if when you `throw` in a function it will be caught on the outside or not. **However, what you want done can be done**.

It is not a 'noob question', and it is very fundamental:

```
 function foo()
    throw new Error(); // I want to know if whoever is calling `foo`
                       // handles this error
 }
```

### First, what you can do

Simply put in the first case:

```
 exampleOne.$promise.then(function (success) {}, function (error) {});
```

What you get is a promise that is *always* fulfilled. However, in the second case the promise might be rejected. Handling a rejection with a rejection handler is like a `catch` in real code - once you handle it it is no longer rejected.

Personally, I would not use an interceptor here, but rather a resource-using pattern since that's more clear with intent, you can wrap it in a function so it won't need a scope but I like that idea less. Here is what I'd do

```
attempt(function(){
    return $resource('/path').save(objectTwo).$promise.
           then(function (success) {});
});

function attempt(fn){
    var res = fn();
    res.catch(function(err){
        // figure out what conditions you want here
        // if the promise is rejected. In your case check for http errors
        showModalScreen();
    }
    return res; // for chaining, catch handlers can still be added in the future, so
                // this only detects `catch` on the function passed directly so 
                // we keep composability
}
```

### Now, a short proof that it can't be done

Let's prove it for fun.

Let's say we are given the code of a program M, we create a new promise `p` and replace every `return` statement in M and`throw` statement in M with a `return p.catch(function(){})` and also add a `return p.catch(function(){})`, now a handler will be added to `p` if and only if running `M` ever terminates. So in short - given code M we have constructed a way to see if it halts based on an existence of a solution to the problem of finding if `catch` is appended to `p` - so this problem is at least as hard as [the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Notice that many instances of the halting problem can be solved. It would be *real fun* to write a statement in a homoiconic language that tests whether it is called from some place that is wrapped in a try-catch clause :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can postpone redirect with zero timeout and give a chance to error handler if any exists to set flag on error object that error was handled:

```
var interceptor = ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
    function error(rejection) {

            return $q.reject(rejection).finally(function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (rejection.errorHandled === true) {
                        alert('all is under control');
                    } else {
                        alert("Houston we've got problems");
                    }
                }, 0); //zero timeout to execute function after all handlers in chain completed
            });
    }

    return {
        'responseError': error
    };
}];

var exampleOne = $resource('/path').save(objectOne);
exampleOne.$promise.then(function (success) { }, function(error) {
    error.errorHandled = true;
});
```

Comment: Why the `$timeout` here? A+ Promises already defer execution to a later point.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I tested this locally and though I expected that `finally` block will be executed at the end of promise chain, it was executed before in-place error handler.

Comment: Yes, but it is executed after the error handler was _attached_. Someone can always _attach_ an error handler at some later point in the future.

Comment: I don't follow you. Feel free to edit my answer with example.

Comment: My first point, is that your code would work if you somehow detect adding `.catch` to the chain. If you don't - I can always produce a counterexample such as `var p = promise(); setTimeout(function(){ p.catch(function{}),2000)` - which it would not detect.

Comment: You mean stituation, when response error handled asynchroniously? Yes, this code shouldn't work in such case.